# creating adb pull bash command

Tags: android, bash, shell, batch-file

When I run below command directly on prompt, it works fine by pulling all files from emulator sdcard:

```
adb -s emulator-5556 pull /sdcard/.
```

However when I create bash file (extract.sh) with above command and run it I get following error:

```
remote object 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/sdcard/' does not exist
```

As can be seen it somehow adds `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git` before it. These are the contents of bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
adb -s emulator-5556 pull /sdcard/.
```

Does anyone have an idea of why it works when direcly typing on prompt and not via bash file ? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Cygwin?

Comment: @enedil: No I am not using it

Comment: So why did you create a bash script? On Windows, it's a batch file (*.bat or *.cmd).

Comment: They run via git console tool, I am already running other bash scripts as well

Comment: Maybe there is the problem? Why don't you create a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you're not specifying the destination directory?  For example, the batch command I use when pulling pictures from my phone over USB is `adb pull "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera" "E:\Phone Pics\HTC DNA"` which specifies both the source directory on the phone and the destination directory on my computer.  As a side note, like enedil I recommend using this in a batch file when working in Windows.

Comment: Please note:  this works in Windows cmd, but not Windows Git Bash / mingw64.  perhaps from Git Bash you can run it with cmd